# Open new Command Prompt and SSH from C Program

Tags: c, ssh, cmd

I am working on a systems project with multiple clients and servers. I have to run my code remotely by SSH'ing onto one of my college machines. The next step in the project requires me to spawn a new server whenever one of the existing ones fail.

I tried using the system command to open a different command prompt and run my server program in it, but somehow I am not able to get it right. Can someone please tell me if it is possible to open a new command prompt on my local system and run a server after SSH'ing to the remote system. Or if there is any other efficient way to do it, please tell me how is that possible.

Below is the code snippet,

```
printf("ENTER COMMAND: ");
while ((message[char_count++] = getchar()) != '\n'){};
if(strncmp("SPAWN SERVER", message, 12) == 0)
    system("cmd.exe /Desktop/brds/Fourth_Milestone_Active/serve.c\\");
printf("%s", spawn_message);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. ssh does not allow you to run a local executable on a remote system if that is what you mean. Please show your attempted code as that may make it clearer.

Comment: I have written my code after SSH'ing into the remote system, it is not on the local machine.

Comment: "but somehow I am not able to get it right". Still, please show your code. We can't point out what you may be doing wrong if we can't see the code.

Comment: Ordinarily, servers are started via `init` or `systemd`. But, I'm gathering that you don't have root access to the remote system. So, you're using `ssh`. You could do: `ssh remote_system /foo/bar/service_launcher` and [on the remote system] that target script is (e.g.) `while (1) /foo/bar/service_program` [loosely]

Comment: @CraigEstey but I want to open a new terminal from the program running on the remote system. I thought if the program is already running on the remote machine, I don't have to SSH again. The problem I am not able to understand is how can I open in a local terminal, I agree that would require SSH though but the program should run on the remote system only.

Comment: What is `/Desktop/brds/Fourth_Milestone_Active/serve.c`? Is it really a C-Source file? Why would you want that as an argument to `cmd.exe`? Generally if you are supposed to maintain X number of servers, there is no need to involve `cmd.exe`. You can simply `fork()` a new process that waits for connection of a set of ports. I guess if what you are saying is you want to start the new server on a remote machine, then establishing a ssh connection to the remote host hand having an executable on that server than will start another server process makes sense.

Comment: If you do `ssh remote_system remote_command` from a terminal window on the local machine [as mentioned above], that is easy. To have the remote system run a script that is _not_ invoked from the local system [via `ssh`] and have it _force_ a popup terminal on the local system is actually a remote code execution [security] vulnerability, so it's not allowed. The remote script invoked via the `ssh` command _can_ [with some more sophistication] check for an already running instance of the server program and not execute it again. But, I return to the method in my original comment.

Comment: Why do you want a remote server to run in a terminal window at all [if you're not using the `ssh` method]? Normally, servers open logfiles on the server system. And, then, you [periodically] do `ssh remote_system cat /foo/bar/server_logfile`